# How do I set custom fonts in React Native?

Tags: react-native, custom-font

My code is as follows:

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import Home from './screens/home';
import * as Font from 'expo-font';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { AppLoading } from 'expo-app-loading';


const getFonts = () => Font.loadAsync({
  'montserrat-regular': require('./assets/fonts/Montserrat-Regular.ttf'),
  'montserrat-medium': require('./assets/fonts/Montserrat-Medium.ttf'),
  'wreath': require('./assets/fonts/insigne - Wreath Halftone Medium.otf'),
});

export default function App() {

  const [fontsLoaded, setFontsLoaded] = useState(false);

  if(fontsLoaded)
  {
    return (
      <Home />
    );
  } else{
    return(
      <AppLoading
        startAsync = {getFonts}
        onFinish={() => setFontsLoaded(true)}
      />
    )
  }
}
```

and this is showing the following error:

```
Render Error
Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of 'App'.
```

The fonts should work as I am learning but it's throwing an error while working propoerly if I remove the fonts

Answer (score 0):

It might be because of your `getFonts` is not async function. Try making it async like below:

```
const getFonts = async () => await Font.loadAsync({
  'montserrat-regular': require('./assets/fonts/Montserrat-Regular.ttf'),
  'montserrat-medium': require('./assets/fonts/Montserrat-Medium.ttf'),
  'wreath': require('./assets/fonts/insigne - Wreath Halftone Medium.otf'),
});
```

Comment: that didn't work, but removing the bracketts around AppLoading did, but now I got another error saying expo-app-loading deprecated in favor of expo-splash-screen